# Checking whether this identity holds: $ \left(\frac{a'(x)}{b'(x)}b(x)\right)'=-a'(x)$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Let $a(x), b(x)$ be two real, twice differentiable functions. I want to check if the following identity holds:
$$ \left(\frac{a'(x)}{b'(x)}b(x)\right)'=-a'(x)$$
After expanding the derivative and performing some algebraic manipulations, we get
$$ \frac{a'' b'-a'b''}{(b')^2}+2a'=0.$$ Any idea on how to make progress from here?

Comment: Let $b(x) = e^x$ and let $a(x) = x$

Comment: Did you try anything ? It does not even work with $a(x)=b(x)=x$ !!!

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to know "if the identity holds" then the answer is no. **The identity does not hold.** If you amend your question to be "when does the identity hold?" then we have something with which to work.

Observe that rather than complicating the identity with the quotient rule, we can write

$$\begin{align} &\left(\frac{a'(x)}{b'(x)}b(x)\right)'=-a'(x)\\\\\implies
&\int\left(\frac{a'(x)}{b'(x)}b(x)\right)'=\int-a'(x) \\\\\implies &
\frac{a'(x)}{b'(x)}b(x)=-a(x) + c\\\\\implies &
\frac{b'(x)}{b(x)} = -\frac{a'(x)}{a(x)+c} \text{ .}\end{align}$$

Whenever two functions satisfy this, they will also satisfy your identity. In fact, if the two functions can satisfy the above for any single constant $c$ then they will still satisfy the original identity.

We can look for viable functions $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ by making a key observation. Observe that

$$ \frac{b'(x)}{b(x)} = -\frac{a'(x)}{a(x)+c} = g(x) $$

for some function $g(x)$. Taking a look at $b(x)$ first, we have that

$$\begin{align} &\int \frac{b'(x)}{b(x)} = \int g(x)\\\\\implies &
\ln|b| = \int_0^x g(t) \text{d}t + C \\\\\implies & 
b(x) = C_1e^{\int_0^x g(t) \text{d}t} \text{ .}\end{align}$$

Then for $a(x)$ we have

$$ \begin{align} &\int \frac{a'(x)}{a(x) + c} = -\int g(x)\\\\\implies &
\ln|a+c| = \int_0^x g(t) \text{d}t + C \\\\\implies & 
a(x) = c + C_2e^{-\int_0^x g(t) \text{d}t} \text{ .}\end{align} $$

This is the solution! For any function $g(x)$, we can generate $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ that satisfy the original identity.

Let's take an example of $g(x)=\frac{1}{2}x$ then

$$ a(x) = c+ C_2 e^{-x^2} $$ and $$ b(x) = C_1 e^{x^2} $$

and your original identity gives

$$\left( \frac{-2C_2x e^{-x^2} }{ 2C_1 x e^{x^2} }\cdot C_1 e^{x^2}\right)' = 2C_2 x e^{-x^2}  $$ which is clearly true.

$$\:$$

$$\:$$

**EDIT:**

Thank you Lutz Lehmann for your comment. Rather than finding a way to generate a pair of functions that satisfy the identity, we can instead provide one function and find the pair for which the identity holds. Recalling that

$$ \frac{b'(x)}{b(x)} = -\frac{a'(x)}{a(x)+c} $$ we can write this out instead as

$$\begin{align} &b'(x) \left( a(x) + c \right) = -b(x) a'(x) \\\\\implies & 
 b'(x)  a(x) + cb'(x)  = -b(x) a'(x)\\\\\implies &
b'(x)  a(x) + b(x) a'(x)  = -cb'(x)\\\\\implies &
\bigg[b(x)a(x)\bigg]'  = -cb'(x)\\\\\implies & 
\int \bigg[b(x)a(x)\bigg]'  =\int -cb'(x) \\\\\implies & 
b(x)a(x)  = -cb(x) + d \\\\\implies & 
b(x)(a(x)+c)  =  d \text{ .} \end{align}$$

Comment: Or you could simply conclude $(a(x)+c)·b(x)=d$ without any middle function $g$.

Answer (score 1):

This identity doesn't hold in general. We have
\begin{align}
&\left(\frac{a'(x)b(x)}{b'(x)}+a(x)\right)'=0\\
\iff &\frac{\Big(a(x)b(x)\Big)'}{b'(x)}=c_1\\
\iff &\bigg(a(x)b(x)-c_1b(x)\bigg)'=0\\
\iff &\Big(a(x)-c_1\Big)b(x)=c_2
\end{align}
This is the required necessary and sufficient condition. (Note that we are implicitly assuming $b'(x)\ne0$, the given equation is not defined otherwise.)

Comment: Then the condition should be understood as $\exists\, c_1,c_2\cdots$. Anyway, there remains the case of $b=0$, which satisfies the condition but not the equation. I am discarding previous comments.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Edited to include that. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

$$ \left(\frac{a'(x)}{b'(x)}b(x)\right)'=-a'(x)$$
Integration leads to :
$$ \frac{a'(x)}{b'(x)}b(x)=-a(x)+c_1$$
$$\frac{a'(x)}{a(x)-c_1}=-\frac{b'(x)}{b(x)}$$
Integrating again :
$$\ln|a(x)-c_1|=-\ln|b(x)|+\text{constant}$$
$$a(x)=\frac{c_2}{b(x)}+c_1$$
Conclusion :

$$\boxed{\text{The identity}\quad\left(\frac{a'(x)}{b'(x)}b(x)\right)'=-a'(x)\quad \text{holds if} \quad a(x)=\frac{c_2}{b(x)}+c_1}\quad$$

If $\quad a(x)\neq\frac{c_2}{b(x)}+c_1\quad$ the identity doesn't hold.

So, you can generate as many identities of this kind as you want simply in arbitrary choosing a function $b(x)$ and constants $c_1$ and $c_2$. Then with $a(x)=\frac{c_2}{b(x)}+c_1 $ you get the corresponding identity.

This is consistent with the latter addition to the first answer from vb628 with $c_1=-c$ and $c_2=d$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the equation is only in terms of $a'$ and $\dfrac{b'}{b}$ so that $a$ is defined to an additive constant and $b$ to a multiplicative constant. $b'=0$ is excluded.

If $a$ is constant the equation is trivially fulfilled and $b$ is arbitrary. Otherwise, we can immediately integrate and write

$$\frac{a'b}{b'}=-a$$

or

$$a'b+ab'=0=(ab)'$$

and a solution is

$$ab=1.$$

Then the original equation amounts to $$b=\frac1{pa+q}$$ where $p,q$ are some constants.